# NoMethodError with Sprites (Compass + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

**Edit:** I am feeling stupid now. It turns out that the problem was in my global.scss:

```
.settings{
    @include site-icons-sprites(settings);
}
```

Instead of site-icons-sprites, I put in site-icon-sprite, and it worked as expected.

---

I am trying to use sprites with Compass in a Rails application, but I keep receiving the following error:

```
NoMethodError on line ["100"] of /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/sprites.rb: undefined method `parent' for nil:NilClass
```

I have two 18x18px images in a folder called app>assets>images>site-icons called settings.png and search.png. My code is as follows:

From modules/_sprites.scss:

```
@import "site-icons/*.png";
@include all-site-icons-sprites;
```

From global.scss:

```
.settings{
    @include site-icons-sprites(settings);
}
```

From my header file:

```
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <%= current_user.display_name %> 
    <span class="settings"> </span>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", :root %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Logout", signout_path %></li>
        <li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

From my compiled application.css file:

```
/* line 50, site-icons/*.png */
.site-icons-sprite, .site-icons-gear, .site-icons-search, .settings .site-icons-gear, .settings .site-icons-search {
  background: url(/assets/site-icons-sd9044365e4.png) no-repeat;
}

/* line 60, ../../../../../../usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/sprites/_base.scss */
.site-icons-gear {
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}

/* line 60, ../../../../../../usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/sprites/_base.scss */
.site-icons-search {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Any ideas what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am feeling stupid now. It turns out that the problem was in my global.scss:

```
.settings{
    @include site-icons-sprites(settings);
}
```

Instead of site-icons-sprites, I put in site-icon-sprite, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if once of your image names starts with a number